# D3 pie chart labels and value inside

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need some help to include VALUE inside the pie chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/o43atxtL/

```
var data=[11975,  5871, 8916, 2868,4999,5994,6810,7619,1871];
```

Label name in different color representation like below image.
 label name with color representation.

```
var data=[DOWRY,KIDNAPPING,INSULT,ASSAULT,CRUELTY,IMPORTATION,IMMORAL,PROHIBITION,INDECENT]
```

[image: Images]

How can I make a header, say 2001 for a pie chart, 2002 for a pie chart, 2003 for a pie chart,2004 for a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a tooltip to appear in the middle of your donut chart. You can do this by:

- Creating a `<div>` element in the main `<body>` of your page, with an `id` of "tooltip" and a `class` of "hidden".
- In your `<style>` section, style your tooltip (accessing it via `#tooltip`) however you want it to appear, and style your `.hidden` class as `display:none`.
- Create a `function` which, when a user mouses over a section of your donut chart (or clicks on it, or whatever), the tooltip loses its `.hidden` class (and thus appears), and appears at the `x` and `y` location between your donut rings.

Some sample code. The `<div>` element:

```
   <div id="tooltip" class="hidden" style="left: 600px, top: 400px">
                    <p><span id="genre">hip hop</span></p>
                </div>
```

The CSS styles:

```
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

The `function` which "reveals" the tooltip:

```
function mouseover(d) {

    d3.select("#tooltip")
        .style("left", "270px") //this is the x location, between the donut
        .style("top", "537px"); //y location, between the donut

        d3.select("#genre")
            .html('<strong>' + d.name + '</strong>'); //this calls the data

    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false); //this unhides the tooltip

};
```

And, finally, calling the function whenever a user hovers over a section of the donut chart (using your code as the base of the example):

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.layout.pie())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(r / 2)
    .outerRadius(r))
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover); //calling the function which reveals tooltip
```

You'll also need to make a `mouseout` function to hide the tooltip again when a user's mouse leaves the donut section.

Hope that helps. Good luck.