# Adding multiple tooltips for SVG nodes after onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to add multiple tooltips to D3 nodes after my javascript button "Find all Matches" is pressed.

Right now, my code is setup so a user clicks on a node. Next when they press the button "Find all matches" it will change the color of all the nodes that having an identical attribute (properties.represents) to blue. The "Find all Matches" button looks like this:

```
    <button id="findRep" onclick="findRep()" type="button">Find all matches</button>
```

When this button is pressed, it calls findRep() function, the code so far looks like this:

```
function findRep() {

    //Dont highlight all the nodes with no represents value
    if (currRepresents !== undefined) {

        //Filter through all nodes to find matches, and color them blue
        svg.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.represents == currRepresents; })
        .style('fill', 'blue')
        // ADD TOOLTIP HERE //
    }
}
```

The node can have the follow properties I might want to show in the tooltip:

1.Node.name

2.Node.type

3.Node.Id

4.Node.properties.represents

How can I add in a tooltip for each node, so that all the nodes that turn blue, also display some of this information in a tooltip? Thank you for your time and help, I'm relatively knew to javascript and just started using D3! Any help would be apperciated. Below I have added the full index.html file.

```
<div id="console">
<button type="button">Find available data</button>
<button id="findRep" onclick="findRep()" type="button">Find all matches</button>
<button id="repMatch" onclick="findRepresents()" type="button">Suggest match</button>
<button type="button">Suggest intermediate</button>
<div id="metainfo"></div>
</div>

<div id="graph">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .node { stroke: #222; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
    .node.Column { fill: #777; }
    .node.Table { fill: #BBB; }
    .node.JoinTable { fill: #999}
    .node.Dataset { fill: #333}
    .link { stroke: #999; stroke-width: 7px; }
    div {height: 100%;}
    html {height: 100%;}
    body {height: 100%;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 1200, height = 800, radius = 20;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-1000).linkDistance(150).size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%").attr("height", "100%")
            .attr("pointer-events", "all");

    var currRepresents = "null";


    d3.json("/Justin/graph", function(error, graph) {
        if (error) return;

        force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links).enter()
                .append("line").attr("class", "link");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes).enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { console.log("Represents: " + d.properties.represents); return "node "+ d.type.toString() })
                .attr("r", radius)
                .style("fill", function(d) {return d.colr; })
                .call(force.drag);

        // html title attribute
        node.append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; })


        var state = false;
        var last = null;
        var current = null;
        node.on("click", function(n)
                {
                    //Return color of nodes back to normal
                    svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(d) { return d.colr; });

                    //d3.json("/node_info", function(error, nodeInfo){if(error) return;})
                    var metainf = "";

                    //Get Represents property from currently selected node
                    currRepresents = n.properties.represents;

                    metainf = metainf.concat("Title: ", n.name, "<br/>Label: ", n.type, "<br/>Represents: ", currRepresents);
                    console.log(metainf);
                    d3.select("#metainfo")
                        .html(metainf);

                    last = current;
                    current = d3.select(this);
                    current.style('fill', 'red');
                    last.style('fill', function(d) { return d.colr; });

                });
    });

    function findRep() {

        //Dont highlight all the nodes with no represents value
        if (currRepresents !== undefined) {

            //Filter through all nodes to find matches, and color them blue
            svg.selectAll(".node")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.represents == currRepresents; })
            .style('fill', 'blue')
            // TOOLTIP HERE //

        }
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you just want the basics on how to make a tooltip, here's [a brief explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948692/d3-pie-chart-labels-and-value-inside/28950230#28950230). Here's [another tooltip SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824846/adding-tooltips-to-pie-chart-using-d3-js). [Scott Murray's book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/) also has a good intro on tooltips (Chapter 10).